# LEFT JOIN needed? WHERE conditions behave similarly to INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, self-join

Trying to do a simple division of counts based on different criterion from the sample table, grouped by movie rating.  I am using the sample SAKILA schema that comes by default with MySQL.

You can see the separate counts I'm expecting to see from these first two queries:

FIRST QUERY:

```
SELECT f1.rating, count(f1.title)
FROM sakila.film f1
WHERE f1.title like '%BA%'
GROUP BY rating
ORDER BY rating ASC
```

FIRST QUERY RESULTS:

```
    rating  count(f1.title)
    G       4
    PG      5
    PG-13   8
    R       6
    NC-17   6
```

SECOND QUERY:

```
SELECT f1.rating, count(f1.title)
FROM sakila.film f1
WHERE f1.title like '%AM%'
GROUP BY rating
ORDER BY rating ASC
```

SECOND QUERY RESULTS:

```
    rating  count(f1.title)
    G       8
    PG      6
    PG-13   9
    R       18
    NC-17   7
```

What I am after is for the G rating to have the division of 4/8, for the PG rating to have the division of 5/6, and so forth.

I had hoped the following query would accomplish this calculation, however to me the LEFT JOIN appears to be acting as an INNER JOIN because these two WHERE conditions only result in 1 movie that contains both 'BA' as well as 'AM', which is why the result is what it is:

PROBLEMATIC QUERY:

```
SELECT f1.rating, count(f1.title)/count(f2.title) 
FROM sakila.film f1
LEFT JOIN sakila.film f2
ON f1.film_id = f2.film_id
WHERE f1.title like '%BA%'
AND f2.title like '%AM%'
GROUP BY rating
ORDER BY rating ASC
```

PROBLEMATIC QUERY RESULTS:

```
    rating  count(f1.title)/count(f2.title) 
    PG-13   1.0000
```

How can I modify the problematic query to divide the counts from the first two queries as intended and group by rating?  Do I need to rewrite the query using a UNION ALL, or can the LEFT JOIN still be used in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT rating,
       SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%BA%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%AM%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS the_ratio
FROM sakila.film
GROUP BY rating
ORDER BY rating ASC
```

Note that your current approach of doing a self-join I think is going in the wrong direction.  Instead, we can just make a single scan of the entire table and count the various titles for each `rating` group.

Comment: Works great, thanks so much for the fast response and for the explanation

Comment: Hi Sidney, please open a new question instead of pasting here as a comment.

Comment: Here it is, thanks:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130476/calculating-acceptance-ratio-with-left-join-and-self-join-and-aggregate-function

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any join.

```
SELECT 
  rating,
  count(if (title like '%BA%', 1, null)) / count(if (title like '%AM%', 1, null))
FROM sakila.film
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Group by 1 / order by 1 means the first column in select

count will not count on any null values