# Calculating acceptance_ratio with LEFT JOIN and SELF JOIN and aggregate function

Tags: mysql, left-join, aggregate-functions, self-join

Trying to calculate daily acceptance ratios from the 'connecting' table which has 4 fields with sample values:

```
date          action         sender_id        recipient_id 
'2017-01-05', 'request_link', 'frank', 'joe' 
'2017-01-06', 'request_link', 'sally', 'ann' 
'2017-01-07', 'request_link', 'bill', 'ted' 
'2017-01-07', 'accept_link', 'joe', 'frank' 
'2017-01-06', 'accept_link', 'ann', 'sally' 
'2017-01-06', 'accept_link', 'ted', 'bill'
```

Because there are 0 accepts and 1 request on 01-05, its daily acceptance ratio should be 0/1 = 0.  Similarly, the ratio for 01-06 should be 2/1, and it should be 1/1 for 01-07.

It is important however that each accept_link has a corresponding request_link where the sender_id of the request_link = the recipient_id of the accept_link (and vice versa).  So here a self-join is required I believe to ensure that Joe accepts Frank's request, regardless of the date.

How can the below query be corrected so that the aggregation works correctly while retaining the required join conditions?  Will the query calculate correctly as is if the two WHERE conditions are removed, or are they necessary?

```
SELECT f1.date, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN f2.action = 'accept_link' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
    SUM(CASE WHEN f2.action = 'request_link' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS acceptance_ratio
FROM connecting f1
LEFT JOIN connecting f2
ON f1.sender_id = f2.recipient_id
LEFT JOIN connecting f2
ON f1.recipient_id = f2.sender_id
WHERE f1.action = 'request_link'
AND f2.action = 'accept_link'
GROUP BY f1.date
ORDER BY f1.date ASC
```

Expected output should look something like:

```
date          acceptance_ratio
'2017-01-05'  0.0000
'2017-01-06'  2.0000
'2017-01-07'  1.0000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What constitutes a count?  Is it one person with a request link and the other with an accept link?  In your example, what would happen if we had four records, two for frank-joe and two for joe-frank?  Would you want to double count in this case?

Comment: Yes, an accept_link count should only be valid when there is a corresponding request_link from the sender.

For simplicity, let's assume in this example that there are only two records for frank-joe and joe-frank, although now that you mention it, I would be curious to see how you might account for multiple records in a query.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Fastest way to get an answer: Show a meaningful set of sample table data along with expected output and logic behind that output.  I don't see a clear answer now, because the question isn't clear.

Comment: My apologies, I have clarified above. Thanks again for reviewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, I don't think you need to be using a self join here.  Instead, just use conditional aggregation over the entire table, and count the number of requests and accepts which happened on each day:

```
SELECT t.date,
       CASE WHEN t.num_requests = 0
            THEN 'No requests available'
            ELSE CAST(t.num_accepts / t.num_requests AS CHAR(50))
       END AS acceptance_ratio
FROM
(
    SELECT c1.date,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c1.action = 'accept_link' AND c2.action IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_accepts,
           SUM(CASE WHEN c1.action = 'request_link' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_requests
    FROM connecting c1
    LEFT JOIN connecting c2
        ON c1.action       = 'accept_link'   AND
           c2.action       = 'request_link'  AND
           c1.sender_id    = c2.recipient_id AND
           c2.recipient_id = c1.sender_id
    GROUP BY c1.date
) t
ORDER BY t.date
```

Note here that I use a `CASE` expression to handle divide by zero, which could occur should a certain day no requests.  I also assume here that the same invitation will not be sent out more than once.

Comment: Thanks,Tim, this helps a lot. Is there a way to also ensure that the sender_id and recipient_id requirements are met? For example, let's say Joe accepts Frank's request, but perhaps Frank's request_link entry in the database was misentered to 'Jo' in which case neither the request_link nor the accept_link should be counted. Is there a way to verify that the ids match as expected before including them in the SUMs?

Comment: @SidneyCarton I gave you an update, I tested locally and it appears to be working.

Comment: Thanks very much, Tim